# How to remove and return a row from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe with n records indexed (0 - n).
I want to remove a row at the 'x' index from the dataframe and store it elsewhere. I essentially am trying to do the equivalent to performing a pop() from a list in Python. Is there any function or easy way to do this using pandas dataframes?

I've tried using the drop() method but that will only return the same dataframe with the row removed.

```
dataframe df
row_needed = df.drop([2], axis=0)
)
```

Given a dataframe df:

```
  A B C D
0 x y z y
1 x y y y
2 y e r z
```

I would like the following returned and the df updated as such when I remove the row at index 1:

```
  A B C D
0 x y z y
2 y e r z
```

Row returned:

```
1 x y y y
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply define your own function which performs the drop inplace but only after storing the desired result:

```py
def drop_return(df, index):
    row = df.loc[index]
    df.drop(index, inplace=True)
    return row
```

With your given example:

```py
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   A  B  C  D
0  x  y  z  y
1  x  y  y  y
2  y  e  r  z

In [17]: drop_return(df, 1)
Out[17]:
A    x
B    y
C    y
D    y
Name: 1, dtype: object

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
   A  B  C  D
0  x  y  z  y
2  y  e  r  z
```

Comment: How does this work?  Doesn't this create a local `df` in the function call?  How does it know to apply `drop` not to the local `df` but to the original `df` which is outside the function scope?  Thank you